# Rank non-normally distributed sets of integers: long read sequencing and phase blocks

Tags: nonparametric, biostatistics, ranking, bioinformatics

I have about 20 arrays of empirical integer values, which are each not normally distributed, with long tails. I am looking for a 'sane and sound' metric on how to sort these distributions, "with increasing integer size". I could think of using the median of each dataset, or the 95 percentile. But that may not be entirely correct due to the unequal and non-normal distributions. Furthermore, for a specific array I want to have a way to say that "most integers in array x are smaller than those in array y", but not necessarily all integers.

Below is a ridges/joy plot of the datasets, of which I have to log-transform the x-axis to make it visible:

[image]

Here is my biological explanation, for those familiar with the terminology:
I am comparing i) the length of phase blocks (contiguous segments of the genome for which we know to which haplotype variants belong) as determined by increasingly long reads (simulated PacBio datasets) with ii) the length of transcripts in the human genome.

I want i) a metric to say that ""reads of length x lead to phase blocks sufficient to phase variants in most genes"" and ii) a reasonable method to rank the datasets (including the transcript lengths) on the plot.

Comment: I would say that the median is a good way to rank the distributions. If the median of $x$ is smaller than the median of $y$, we will have that "most integers in array $x$ are smaller than those in array $y$". (The 50% lowest values in $x$ are smaller than each of the 50% highest values in $y$).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, guess I'll do that then :)